# Tastypie resources.py attribute error. request.method.lower()

Tags: django, python-2.7, tastypie

When I try POST or GET methods to the resource URL(127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/login/) Im getting the below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mithu/pipliko/pipliko/load_projects/api.py", line 55, in login
    self.method_check(self,allowed=['post','get'])
  File "/home/mithu/pipliko/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 519, in method_check
    request_method = request.method.lower()
  File "/home/mithu/pipliko/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 186, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: method

my api.py

def prepend_urls(self):

```
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<users>%s)/login%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
        url(r'^(?P<users>%s)/logout%s$' %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
    ]
```

def login(self,request,**kwargs):

```
try:
    print request.method
    self.method_check(self,allowed=['post','get'])
except Exception,e:
    print traceback.format_exc()
    #or
    print sys.exc_info()[0]
data = self.deserialize(request,request.raw_post_data,format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
username = data.get('username','')
password = data.get('password','')
authenticKey = authenticate(username = username,password = password)
if authenticKey:
    if authenticKey.is_active:
        login(request,authenticKey)
        return self.create_response(request,{'success':False, 'user':{'id':user.id}})
    else:
        return self.create_response(request,{'success':False,'reason':'Account disabled'},HttpForbidden);
else:
    return self.create_response(request,{'success':False,'reason':'Wrong credentials'},HttpUnauthorized);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use method_check in incorrect way. Try use request instead of self:

`self.method_check(request, ['post','get'])`

Docs: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#method-check